# Log4j2 Error appears as Fatal message when following a tutorial

Tags: java, spring-boot, maven, log4j2

I am trying to follow the below tutorial to add Log4j2 logging to my Spring application. https://www.dataset.com/blog/maven-log4j2-project/

When testing out Log4j2 in application, the FATAL level log is appearing as an ERROR level.

Logger code:
private static final Logger logger = LogManager.getLogger(BookshelfAppServer.class);

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        logger.trace("We've just greeted the user!");
        logger.debug("We've just greeted the user!");
        logger.info("We've just greeted the user!");
        logger.warn("We've just greeted the user!");
        logger.error("We've just greeted the user!");
        logger.fatal("We've just greeted the user!");`
```

Console output:

```
18:25:43.034 [main] DEBUG com.kengo.BookshelfAppServer - We've just greeted the user!
18:25:43.036 [main] INFO com.kengo.BookshelfAppServer - We've just greeted the user!
18:25:43.036 [main] WARN com.kengo.BookshelfAppServer - We've just greeted the user!
18:25:43.036 [main] ERROR com.kengo.BookshelfAppServer - We've just greeted the user!
18:25:43.036 [main] ERROR com.kengo.BookshelfAppServer - We've just greeted the user!
```

I have tried changing the root level in the config folder, updating log4j2 dependencies to the latest version with no luck.

Comment: Can you share your log4j2.xml file?

Comment: can you change the content of the logged message for example also adding the error level in the logged message to confirm the logger.fatal() really log as ERROR level ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Spring Boot configures loggers for you.

If you didn't do any other configuration Spring Boot will pass the input from the Logger interface onto SLF4J, which then in turn will pass it on to the default logger (which is Logback if you did not explicitly change it)

The fatal level is not supported by SLF4J under the assumption that actutal fatal errors should not be something to be logged while the application goes on.

This is why when you use multiple level of Logging bridges the log.fatal method is downgraded to a mere error level.

Logging in Spring Boot is somewhat different to plain Log4J, therefore the tutorial you found might not actually help you.
It might be easier to lookup the doc for Spring Boot Logging directly or have a look at the Logging in Spring Boot Baeldung article

Comment: Thank you sir for your answer, will check out the resources you have suggested :)

Comment: "when you use multiple level of Logging bridges the log.fatal method is downgraded to a mere error level"—that is why a possible solution is to use Log4j2 Core as backend instead of the standard Logback.